# Parsing json using groovy build in tools

Tags: json, groovy

It looks like duplicate, but please help me to create a correct query with a correct tools. I would like to execute this script on Jenkins machine, so I don't want to mess around with additional libraries. 
I would like to have a List of all `id` where e.g.(`name` is 'Test79' and `tags` contains 'launch_QA-350') 
I have such json structure:

```
    //...     
    {
    "content": [
        {
            "id": "5641cde5bfcd0b0485326b83",
            "name": "Test79",
            "tags": [
                "launch_QA-350",
                "2628991879",
                " 2628991879"],
            "isPr": false
        }
    ]
}
```

---

(UPDATE) I already find Java-like solution:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def slurper = new JsonSlurper();
def result = slurper.parseText(jsObj);
for(def cont : result.content){
    if(cont.name == "Test79" && cont.tags.contains("launch_QA-350"))
        println(cont.id)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a *groovier* way:

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsObj)
assert ['5641cde5bfcd0b0485326b83'] == 
    json.content.findAll({ it.name == 'Test79'  && it.tags.contains('launch_QA-350') }).id
```

or

```
assert ['5641cde5bfcd0b0485326b83'] == 
    json.content.findAll({ it.name == 'Test79'  && 'launch_QA-350' in it.tags }).id
```